# How do I get the assembly name in DotNet framework 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

So via this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netframework-1.1) I see `typeof(someClass).Assembly` should return the assembly name. Visual studio is complaining that the `Assembly` property is not valid. Are there any dependencies I need to include in my project to get this property?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using such old version as .NET FW 1.1

Comment: Do you mean the fullname property of assembly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.fullname?view=netframework-1.1

Comment: I have a feeling that something else is actually going on.  Can you show the *exact* line of code that you have?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I know it is frustrating sometimes but I know some projects where legacy systems needs to be extended or the customer needs to use Win XP without SP2. :-)

Comment: @SebastianSiemens Win 2k and Win XP can target .net 2.0, afaik

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 is the [best choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-xp) for XP.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core 1.1? that one would not have an Assmbly property on `System.Type` (reintroduced in .NET Core 2.0)

Comment: I was using 1.1 to support dotNet 4.5 but it turns out our project was actually 4.6.2 so I've moved to framework 2.0 which doesn't have this problem